# Android/iOS WiFi Mac Randomization

Tags: android, python, ios, wifi, packet-sniffers

**Update:**

To give a bit more context, I specialized on tracking mobile devices but as it seems Android and iOS come with a mechanism to randomize WiFi MAC addresses over time to counteract that tracking. If you are interested in the topic, you should have a look at this paper:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.02874.pdf

---

I have collected logfiles with up to 100k entries of hashed Mac addresses.

But it looks like my MD5 hash didn't work properly. I think some Mac addresses got different hashes.

For Hashing I used the following code:

```
import hashlib
from scapy.all import *

    def PacketHandler(packet):
        if packet.haslayer(Dot11):
            mac = hashlib.md5(packet.addr2.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

Where *packet.addr2* is used from the scapy module, a wifi sniffing module.
Is there a possibility that this didn't work as intented?

Comment: Can you give an example of where you are seeing differences?

Comment: There is the problem. I've kind of tracked multiple different devices. But the recorded amount of "unique" devices is totally unrealistic. It is significantly larger as it should be. So I hoped somehow could see an error in this line of code.

Comment: It's quite likely that the error is not in this line of code unless packet.addr2 has some sort of anomaly. Where does this `packet` come from and what does `addr2` mean would be more important.

Comment: I've edited my post. It is a wifi packet, captured by using scapy as module.

Comment: I would suggest you log the actual mac address and look at raw data. And additionally: Depending on what you tried and did it may be possible that you caught all wifi packets there are. And then every person that walked by will have left it's stamp in your logs. That may be a possibility too.

Comment: After a bit of research I probably found the reason of the problem.
Android and Apple try to randomize their MAC addresses over time.
Anyone that is interested in WiFi tracking should take a look:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.02874.pdf

Comment: That `.encode('utf-8')` looks suspicious. Even if it happens to not cause problems, change it to `.encode('ascii')` to be clearer.

Comment: I'll do but unfortunately I will not have the chance to test it in a big environment in the near future again. So I will not know if it has an impact. But I might have found the problem. Have a look at the update in my first post. Thank you!